# JAX-WS array - The method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, arrays, web-services

I get an error message when passing by an array via webservice JAX-WS (Java client and Java server):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method insertIgnoreMultipleUsers(StringArray) in the type Queue is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652921/using-java-jax-ws-to-return-a-string-array) I read that List is a possible solution.
But when altering to List I get a similar message.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499295/can-you-return-an-array-from-a-jax-ws-webmethod) they advise to use arrays, but in my case that does not work.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thank's in advance!